# Pushing value on a global array in php

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am facing a problem in pushing value to a global array.

A user uploads multiple documents. Everytime he uploads a document, a webservice is called which returns 'id' and 'type' (which is working fine). I need to store it in a array so that I can encode it into JSON and send it when the user clicks on Submit button.

My code is:

```
//global variable
<?php
$idarray = array();
$typearray = array();
?>

//form
<form method="post">
<input type="submit" name="upload" value="Upload">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['upload']))
{
   include 'webservice_call.php';           
   $url='http://localhost:8080/MyProject/getEntityRequest';
   $response=curl_get_call($url); //this function is inside webservicecall.php
   $json_string = json_decode($response);

   $id=$json_string->gstdtls->entcd; //this is working fine
   $ty=$json_string->gstdtls->stcd; //this is working fine

   func1($idarray, $typearray, $id, $ty);
}

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
   $docls=array();
   global $idarray;
   global $typearray;
   for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($idarray); $i++) { 
   $docls[] =  array (
            'id' => $idarray[$i],
            'ty' => $typearray[$i],         
             );
   }
$json_formatted['docls']=$docls;
echo json_encode($json_formatted);
}

function func1($idarray, $typearray, $a, $b){
   array_push($idarray, $a);
   array_push($typearray, $b);
}
?>
```

When the user finally submits, it should give me the content of an array in a encoded format. Which is not happening. I know I am not using the global array in the way it should be used.

Comment: you want to sent `$json_formatted` on submit??

Comment: Yes. When the user hits the Submit button, the information stored in the array should be sent in JSON format. But I am having problem in storing the values in the array.

Comment: `isset($_POST['upload']`  is it coming from other page or same

Comment: It is coming from the "form" in the same page.

Comment: what is this `$json_string->gstdtls->entcd` and `$json_string->gstdtls->stcd`   , arrays??

Comment: I am getting the 'id' and 'type' from the JSON as a response. (This is working fine as I can echo this). The problem is I need to push this in an array.

Comment: so what i can understand is:  upload will b called no of times and it will push values in arrays (idarray,typearray)  and when you click on submit it will convert it in json and echo it??

Comment: This is exactly what I am trying to do. I think I don't need to use function 'func1()' but put the content of the function inside the if(isset($_POST['upload'])). But the problem is still not solved.

Comment: what u need is to store values somewhere like database or session instead of an array when you call upload and when you call submit button retrieve those values and convert them to json and echo them

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have to store two values in the session, document id and type multiple times. Therefore I would request you to kindly suggest on the same. Further it would be a great help if you could kindly share your email id please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what u need is to store values somewhere like database or session instead of an array when you call upload and when you call submit button retrieve those values and convert them to json and echo them .

Here is a example of that using session

```
        <?php
        $json_formatted=array();
        if (!session_start()) {
            session_start();
        }
        ?>


        <?php
        if(isset($_POST['upload']))
        {

           $_SESSION["idarray"][]=rand(0,5);
           $_SESSION["typearray"][]=rand(0,5);

        }

        if(isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
           $docls=array();
           $idarray=$_SESSION["idarray"];
           $typearray=$_SESSION["typearray"];
           for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($idarray); $i++) { 
           $docls[] =  array (
                    'id' => $idarray[$i],
                    'ty' => $typearray[$i],         
                     );
           }
        $json_formatted['docls']=$docls;
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r(json_encode($json_formatted));
        echo "</pre>";
        session_destroy();

        }

        function func1($idarray1, $typearray1, $a, $b){
           array_push($idarray, $a);
           array_push($typearray, $b);
        }
        ?>


        <form method="post">
        <input type="submit" name="upload" value="Upload">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
```